# Finding aggregate return for multiple entries under same name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, search-indexing

I would like to find the aggregate return in an excel for trading entries.

I have 3 columns, A - name, B - Buy, C - Sell.

For instance Sally first entry is Buy 2 and then later on Buy 3, and her last entry would be Sell 7, so her return would be (-2 -3 +7) = +2. So, there could be multiple Sells and Buys.

If there were only one Buy and Sell, I could use 'VLOOKUP', but it always gives me only the first entry's result it finds. So I could only get the (-2 +7) = 5, which is incorrect.

What formula should I use, and how to find the right result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can try to provide a sample table here.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this solution helps.

[image]

Formula in I3 is

```
=(-SUM(IF($D$3:$D$9=H3,$E$3:$E$9,0))+SUM(IF($D$3:$D$9=H3,$F$3:$F$9,0)))
```

This needs to be converted to Array Formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar.

The formula will enclose in Curly Braces.

If there's no entry leave that cell at zero.
If Buy numbers are already entered as negative value, remove the minus sign from the formula.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me, but I get a "#N/A"
This is what I use, I also have the "J2225" inside the column, but if I take it out like it is in your excel, it still doesn't work.
{=(-SUM(IF($J$2:$J$2230=J2225;$M$2:$M$2230;0))+SUM(IF($J$2:$J$2230=J2225;$N$1:$N$2230;)))}

Even if I do the Array Formula, I still get the same result. Shouldn't I be using VLOOKUP here as well?

Comment: If I correctly understand, the both array sizes should match. You are returning M2:M2230 in first part but N1:N2230 in other. You may need to change it to N2:N2230. Please check this. Also this must be an Array Formula to work correctly.

Comment: With my above observation I could reproduce your issue. See this screenshot 
 https://i.imgur.com/43LlEot.png